# paypal echecks need some explanation

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have read a lot of stuff and spent hours on studying the PPs API.

There is one thing I don't understand and would like to know how can I do this.

When sender sends money form the bank account (not cc) it's called echeck and it takes up to 5 days.
In some places I can see that people say

- you can't cancel echeck once it's approved. you can only ask seller to cancel your request/ payment.
  but on some other sites I can read
- buyer can cancel transfer any time, so do not ship the items untill you get final confirmation.

So what's the final answer here, can the buyer cancell the echeck/ transfer or not?
What if they approve it, but after one minute get rid of all the money form the account, and there is nothing they can be charged for?

And the second question: I can see that in the account setting you can disable acceptance od echecks. but how can this be done via API? I mean on my website I will have different sellers and I can't check if they have echeck enabled or not, so I would like to block echecks automatically via api. So, how can I block echecks using API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buyers can't cancel an eCheck once they've initiated it.  They would have to request a refund from you after the eCheck completes.  (P.S. -- it's always a good idea to wait for the eCheck to complete before giving the buyer their goods.  Just because an eCheck was initiated doesn't automatically mean that it will clear -- the withdraw from their bank account could still fail.)

If you're using Express Checkout, you can set `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD=InstantPaymentOnly` to disable eChecks.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using preapproved payments.

Comment: Ok, there are a couple of alternatives.  First, there is a setting in the PayPal account that can be turned on to block eChecks.  The receiver of the payment would need to turn this setting on.  Log in to the PayPal account and go to Profile->My Selling Tools (or, if you're on the new account interface, More->Settings->My selling tools).  Click on the **Update** link next to **Block payments**.  Then, under "Block the following payments", click "Pay with eCheck or German bank transfer for all website payments except eBay."

Comment: (Continued) The other alternative is to use the `allowedFundingType` parameter in your Pay request and set it so to only allow payments from the PayPal balance or a credit card; however, you'll need to request special permissions from PayPal to use this parameter.  See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/ for more information on this parameter.